# Is it possible to flip the mirrored object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

This is a general 3D question, if this is possible in an application like Maya, 3Ds Max, etc, that would be nice to know. But I am using Blender right now.

I am wondering whether it's possible to flip the mirrored object; normally when you mirror something, obviously, it flips. That's the definition of mirroring.

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Is this possible using some sort of mirror modifier?

Comment: Isn't that what the array modifier does?

Comment: That's NOT the definition of mirroring. @Ron Jensen is right, you're looking for the Array modifier

Comment: I realize this is what the array modifier does, but I am just wondering whether you can do this with the mirror mod somehow.

I can try to figure out a workaround myself I guess. But theres a really neat thing with the mirror mod, called "Bisect"; if the array mod had this, that would be nice; all it has is "Weld". Looking up "Bisect" on google leads to a different result unfortunately.

Comment: You could try with collection instance like in here, BUT only steps 1 and 2: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184426/ctrlm-interactive-mirror-is-not-taking-the-objects-rotation-into-account/184429#184429

Comment: @LukasKawalec Could you elaborate more about **bisect** in mirror modifier? It's hard to think what is the "bisect" in mirror modifier when people are not familiar with other 3D tools. And for me, a coder, bisect seems to be a common sorting, searching algorithm method. And also some usage scenario would be appreciated.

Comment: @Emir Unfortunately I don't think you can have the instanced object bisect the real one, which would be nice in my case... but that is really cool, I will probably be going back to that if I need something like that

Comment: @HikariTW https://youtu.be/SWG5AyACIVM hope that explains it

Comment: I highly recommend you to explain more about your final goal, so someone can describe different methods  for you to try. Because, just with the images, collection instance is an option,. But i don't know if you need an specific movement or an animation or an specific manipulation

Comment: @Emir The reason I haven't explained my final goal is because it's a very personal, creative, and stupid idea, but I do have reasons for it. Nonetheless I made a short video for you to help explain.

https://youtu.be/9fKimDvAUvc

Comment: Have you seen [rotational arrays](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6m5r7Uq-Khg) using object offsets? Or using [the object offset to build a single object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhYom1n0qZs)

Comment: I know about all of that, actually; this is part of a goal of mine to radial array with my own twist around it, which currently requires bisecting the mesh in degrees like 180 (2 copies), 120 (3 copies), 90 (4 copies (can just use the mirror modifier twice though), 72 (5 copies), 60 (6 copies), etc etc etc. But yes, I know lots of ways to radial array.

One of my ideas was to use the mirror mod here, but it's kind of superseded by the bisect thing I am figuring out right now.